# Can Valgrind show the value of the leaked memory?

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind

I am wondering if there is a possibility in valgrind to show the value of the leaked memory, such as (NOT a real valgrind output!):

```
==15060== 12 bytes (***HERE***) in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==15060==    at 0x4C2AAA4: operator new[](unsigned long) (in vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==15060==    by 0x5DC8236: char* allocate(unsigned long, char const*, long) (mem.h:149)
==15060==    by 0x5EAC286: trim(char const*, nap_compiler const*) (file.cpp:107)
```

Where the `***HERE***` shows the exact value of the string that is being leaked. I've been looking all over the documentation, but found nothing. Maybe someone more familiar with the tool can point out what to do to achieve this! (I'm not afraid of compiling it myself :) )

Comment: Tehnically, it should be possible. Valgrind (Memcheck) stores shadow values to remember every heap access. I have understood that it is relatively easy to develop tools (like Memcheck, in this case). If you are not afraid of recompiling Valgrind, you can modify Memcheck to display values like this. It is probably more time-consuming than fixing your error, however. ;)

Comment: an alternative would be dumping the leaks to files, which would work better for larger leaks.

Answer (score 2):

GDB server in Valgrind version >= 3.8.0 provides the monitor command
    block_list 
which will output the addresses of the leaked blocks.

You can then examine the leaked memory content using GDB commands such as x.

For more information, see
http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver
and
http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands